# How to print \par \framebreak in .txt file using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, visual-studio-code, text

I want write the following lines in .txt file using Python code. But \f in "\framebreak" causes problem.  I am new to python. Please help.

The lines are as follows:

\par
\framebreak

Comment: \\par\\framebreak

Answer (score 0):

`\f` is a special char in python, just like `\n` or `\r`.
If you want to write `\` in your file, please use `\\`

For example:

```
>>> print("Use \n to make new line!")
Use 
 to make a new line!
>>> print("Use \\n to make a new line!")
Use \n to make a new line!
>>> print("\par \framebreak")
\par ♀ramebreak
>>> print("\\par \\framebreak")
\par \framebreak
```

So the solution is replace all `\` by `\\`